# Self-made jQuery plugin triggered but not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I wrote a simple plugin to validate if input fields that needs to be number are indeed numbers.

The plugin can be successfully loaded and triggered, but it doesn't do anything. However, if I manually type $(selector).validateNum(); in the console, it works perfectly. Anyone knows why?

Please check this jsBin for the live version:

jsBin: http://jsbin.com/tusunuweto/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Code below:

```
  $.fn.validateNum = function () {
    console.log('validation started');
    var numInputFields = this.find('input.number');

    $(numInputFields).each(function () {
      if ( isNaN( Number( $(this).val() ) ) ) {
        $(this).keyup(function () {
          alert("This field must be a number");
        });
      }
    });
  };
```

In my index.html file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(function() {
    $('#selector').validateNum();
  });

</script>
```

Comment: Does `$('#selector')` exist when you call `$('#selector').validateNum();`?

Comment: Yes it does already exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of issues I see

**You're not chaining properly**

This isn't inherently bad (because `.find` does work the way you've used it) but it could afford to be more explicit. For example, if you call `$(".foo, .bar").validateNum()` it should be clear that it's going to find inputs in each selected element

You'll see this pattern very commonly in other community plugins

```
$.fn.myPlugin = function() {
  // `this` is the jQuery object that matches the selected elements

  // don't forget `return` to make your plugin chainable
  return this.each(function() {
    // iterate through the selected elements performing some operation
  });
};
```

But! as you'll see next, we don't even need to use `.find` at all!

---

**You're not using event delegation**

You're specifically binding a `.keyup` listener to each input. If there's a lot of inputs on your page, this could become very resource usage intensive.

This method uses delegation so you're not binding a listener to every single input

```
$.fn.validateNum = function() {
  console.log("validation started");
  return this.each(function() {
    $(this).on("keyup", ".number", function(event) {
      var num = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
      if (isNaN(num)) {
        alert("This field must be a number");
      }
    });
  });
};

$(".testPlugin").validateNum();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to move your isNaN check into the click handler, I also added a regex to remove non numbers.

This works, but if you want to do validation like this, you might want to look into a library like [.validate](http://jqueryvalidation.org/)

```js
 $(function () {

     $.fn.validateNum = function () {
         console.log('validation started');
         var numInputFields = this.find('input.number');
         $(numInputFields).each(function () {
             $(this).keyup(function () { // you need to move your isNaN check into the click handler
                 if (isNaN(Number($(this).val()))) {
                     $(this).val( $(this).val().replace(/[^0-9.]/g, "") ); // added this to remove non-numbers
                     alert("This field must be a number");
                 }
             });
         });
     };
     
     $(".testPlugin").validateNum();
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="testPlugin">
<input class="number" />
```